# WPF C# .NET Core Compiler-error when compiling for osx-x64

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, visual-studio, .net-core

When I tried to compile my WPF C# .NET Core project for "osx-64" I got this error:

There was no runtime package available for "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" for the specified runtime identifier "osx-x64".

What can I do? Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2144

Answer (score 1):

WPF in .NET Core is **only** available on **Windows**, see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0).

> One of the biggest enhancements is support for Windows desktop applications (Windows only). By using the .NET Core 3.0 SDK component Windows Desktop, you can port your Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. **To be clear, the Windows Desktop component is only supported and included on Windows**.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I've thought that the advantage over the .NET Framework is that I can use the .NET Core on Win, Lin and Mac... Is there any opinion to compile this program for MacOS? And in the "publish" section of Visual Studio i have the opinion to compile to other platforms, then what is this for?

Comment: @pavil Indeed the advantage of .NET Core is that it can be run on Windows, Linux and MacOS. However, that is not true for the UI Frameworks WPF and WinForms, because they rely on the Windows API. They were ported to .NET Core just so that developers that use them can also move on with .NET Core and benefit from its improvements, because WPF and WinForms applications are still prominent.